# Amazon ECS - CredentialsV2Request: ID not found - cloudwatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created my first ECS Cluster, EC2 - task and service. My containers keep on exiting without any logs. When ssh into container instance and do docker logs  I get the following message:

Error response from daemon: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: CredentialsEndpointError: failed to load credentials
caused by: InvalidIdInRequest: CredentialsV2Request: ID not found

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `ECS_Execution_Role_Policy`.

it should be including `logs` permission for `cloudwatch`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and add `awslogs` driver into `ecs.config`

```
ECS_CLUSTER=test_ecs_cluster
ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS=["awslogs","json-file"]
```

> See :
>
> Here's [a document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html)